# Sampling from distribution parametrized by $ \log(1-p) $ given $ \log (p) $

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, genetic-algorithms, evolutionary-algorithms, simulated-annealing

The context for the problem is that I'm working with a modified genetic algorithm where the fitness score of each chromosome is given by a log-probability $ \log(p) \in (-\infty, 0) $. Thus, I have a categorical distribution parameterized by (unnormalized) log-probabilities. These scores are large in magnitude, so I want to be able to sample from this distribution *without* needing to first exponentiate and normalize, as exponentiating would lead to numerical over/underflow errors during program execution. I know that I can sample proportional to $ p $ without exponentiation by using the Gumbel-max trick.

However, what's giving me trouble is how, given this set of log-probabilities $ \log(p) $ , I would be able to sample from a distribution parameterized by $ \log(1 - p)$ . The motivation for this is that I want to "kill off" lowest-scoring chromosomes in the population, hence driving up overall population fitness. It is not possible to directly convert $\log(p)$ to $\log(1 - p)$ by logarithm rules, and as such I'm struggling to find some kind of transformation that will allow me to do this.

How should I go about thinking of a solution to this? Is this sort of thing even possible?

Comment: What distribution are you sampling from?

Comment: @Sycorax Thanks for the clarifying question -- it is not a standard distribution, and I've just added some edits to my question for some more context.

Answer (score 0):

> It is not possible to directly convert $\log(p)$ to $\log(1−p)$ by logarithm rules...

*Au contraire mon ami*, it is indeed possible.  Since $p \geqslant 0$ you have $p = \exp(\log p)$ (allowing computation for infinities) so you can express the required quantity as:

$$\begin{align}
\log(1-p) 
&= \log(1 - \exp(\log p)) \\[6pt]
&= \log(1 - \exp(-(-\log p))) \\[6pt]
&= \text{log1mexp}(-\log p). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Thus, if you already have the value $a = \log p$ you can get the desired quantity as:

$$\log(1-p) = \text{log1mexp}(-a).$$

This transformation can be implemented in `R` using the [`log1mexp` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/VGAM/versions/1.1-2/topics/log1mexp) in the `VGAM` package (also see [Mächler 2012](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/vignettes/log1mexp-note.pdf) for some discussion of computational issues for this function).  Incidentally, this function is closely related to the hyperbolic functions in trigonometry.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your answer and the link to the paper. This seems like a sensible approach -- however, the issue is that it exponentiates the log-probabilities during computation. I'm dealing with fairly large log-probabilities (i.e. abs($\log (p) ) > 1000$ ), and I begin hitting numerical overflow errors for abs($\log (p) ) > 750 $. 

Ideally, I wouldn't have to exponentiate at all (as is the case for the Gumbel Max Trick).